# I'm writing a fuel conversion program and its not working :(

Tags: python

I am a novice python code writer and i am starting small with a fuel conversion program. The program asks for your name and then converts a miles per gallon rate or a kilometers per litre rate. Currently, the program runs fine until it gets to the convert to MPG line. then once you press y, it does nothing. funny thing is, no syntax error has been returned. please help as i cannot find anything on it :(

```
import time

y = 'y', 'yes', 'yep', 'yea', 'ye'
n = 'n', 'no', 'nup', 'nay'

name = str(input("Hey, User, whats your name?   "))

time.sleep(1.5)

print("Alright", name, "Welcome the the *gravynet* Fuel Efficiency Converter!")

time.sleep(1.5)

str(input("Would you like to convert the fuel efficiency of your motor vehcile? (Miles Per Gallon) (y/n):    "))

if y is True:

miles = int(input("How far did you travel (in miles):   "))

galls = int(input("How much fuel did you consume (in gallons):   "))

 mpgc = (galls/miles)

 print("The MPG Rate is:  ", int(mpgc))

 time.sleep(2)

 print("test print")
if y is (not True):

  input(str("Would you like to convert KPL instead? (y/n):   "))

  time.sleep(1.5)

  if y is True:

   kilometers = int(input("How far did you travel (in kilometers):   "))

   litres = int(input("How much fuel did you consume (in litres):   "))

   kplc = ( litres / kilometers )

   print("The KPL Rate is:   ", int(kplc))

   time.sleep(3)

   exit()


  if y is not True:

   print("No worries")

   time.sleep(1.5)

   print("Thanks", name, "for using *gravynet* Fuel Efficiency Coverter")

   time.sleep(1.5)

   print("Have a good day!")

   time.sleep(1.5)

   exit()

  else :
     print("Sorry, invalid response. Try again")
     exit()


elif not y:

  print("Please use y/n to answer" )

  time.sleep(2)

elif not n:

  print("Please use y/n to answer" )

  time.sleep(2)
```

sorry if you think that is bad but i just started python and i need some help :)

Comment: Well for one thing, `if y is True` makes no sense.  It will always be false.  `y` is a constant tuple.  And it's not the literal `True`.

Comment: By the way, in python, `is` means something different. Just use `==` for now.

Answer (score 1):

Severely trimmed down and indentation fixed (I think....)

`if y is True` and similarly `if y is not True` make no sense here.

Also, speaking of `is`.. `is` and `==` may be work as equivalent expressions sometimes for checking for "equality", but not necessarily. `==` checks for equality whereas `is` checks for object identity. You should use `==` for checking for equality between two objects. Except for `None` in which case it's generally preferred to use `is` instead of `==` for this.

You're converting to `str` in a bunch of places unnecessarily. They're already strings.

In your mpg conversion you already have a floating point number (possibly an int). There's no need to convert to an int here. Suppose mpg is < 1. Then `int` casting will make this return zero

Your math is also backwards. miles *per* gallon. Similarly, kilometers *per* gallon.

```
name = input("Hey, User, whats your name?   ")
print("Alright", name, "Welcome the the *gravynet* Fuel Efficiency Converter!")
mpg = input("Would you like to convert the fuel efficiency of your motor vehcile? (Miles Per Gallon) (y/n): ")

if mpg in y:

    miles = int(input("How far did you travel (in miles):   "))
    galls = int(input("How much fuel did you consume (in gallons):   "))

    mpgc = miles / galls

    print("The MPG Rate is:  ", mpgc)

else:
    kpl = input("Would you like to convert KPL instead? (y/n):   ")

    if kpl in y:
        kilometers = int(input("How far did you travel (in kilometers):   "))
        litres = int(input("How much fuel did you consume (in litres):   "))
        kplc = kilometers / litres
        print("The KPL Rate is:   ", kplc)

    else:

        print("No worries")
        print("Thanks", name, "for using *gravynet* Fuel Efficiency Coverter")
        print("Have a good day!")
```

Comment: thankyou so much, i was not aware of the usage of 'in' and it is much appreciated that you share this knowledge. thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The `is` keyword in python checks if two variables point to the same location in memory. `y` will never point to the same memory location as the singleton `True` because it's value is a string. I suspect what you mean to do is something like

```
inp = str(input("Would you like to convert the fuel efficiency of your motor vehcile? (Miles Per Gallon) (y/n):    "))
if inp in y:
    ...
```

Comment: yes, Pythonista mentioned the same thing in the above comment. Thank you as well for your input ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly take `y` as pressed from the keyboard, you have to take it as an input(Pressing enter would be required), store it, check if it satisfies the conditions, then apply the logic.

I see you tried to define y and n as a tuple (deliberately or not), In that case I assume you also want to take those other words as `yes` or `or` too.

In that case you can apply this logic;

```
inp = input("Would you like to convert the fuel efficiency of your motor vehcile? (Miles Per Gallon) (y/n):    ")
if inp in y: # Check if inp corresponds any of the words defined in y
    # Things to do if `yes` or anything similar entered.
```

Some notes:

- You don't need to use `str()` after you take input if you are using
  Python3 (Which seems you are). Because `input()` returns string.
- In somewhere you did something like this:

  `input(str("Would you like to convert KPL instead? (y/n):   "))`

  Which is even more reduntant because the value you entered is already
  a string.
- You also didn't assign some inputs to any variable throughout the
  code. You should assign them If you are to use them later.

Please take care of these issues.

Comment: Thank you for the hints and tips, I have learnt to use    input = 123, if input in y then:....      But thanks anyway for helping